# How can I use 'update where' select in FoxPro?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am totally new to FoxPro (and quite fluent with MySQL).

I am trying to execute this query in FoxPro:

```
update expertcorr_memoinv.dbf set 'Memo' = (select 'Memo' from expertcorr_memoinv.dbf WHERE Keymemo='10045223')  WHERE Keydoc like "UBOA"
```

I got the error:

> function name is missing )

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a few sample data, and an expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In FoxPro SQL statements you would not 'single-quote' column names. In Visual FoxPro version 9 the following sequence would run without errors:

```
CREATE TABLE expertcorr_memoinv (keydoc Char(20), keymemo M,  Memo M)

Update expertcorr_memoinv.dbf set Memo = (select Memo from expertcorr_memoinv.dbf WHERE Keymemo='10045223')  WHERE Keydoc like "UBOA"
```

If you would provide a few sample data and an expected result, we could see whether the line you posted would do what you want after correcting the single-quoted 'Memo' names.

**NB 1**: "Memo" is a reserved word in FoxPro.

**NB 2**: As you know, the ";" semicolon is a line-continuation in Visual FoxPro, so that a longer SQL statement can be full; of; those;

So that the *Update* one-liner could be written as:

```
Update expertcorr_memoinv ;
    Set Memo = (Select Memo From expertcorr_memoinv ;
        WHERE Keymemo='10045223') ;
    WHERE Keydoc Like "UBOA"
```

**NB 3:** Alternatively, you can SQL `Update .... From...` in Visual FoxPro, similar to the Microsoft [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) feature. See *[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)*

Comment: the table has a column name called "Memo"

Comment: Sure, and it works in most cases, but it's still a reserved word in the `foxpro` programming language

Answer (score 1):

I would do that just as Stefan showed.
In VFP, you also have a chance to use non-SQL statements which make it easier to express yourself. From your code it feels like KeyMemo is a unique field:

```
* Get the Memo value into an array
* where KeyMemo = '10045223'
* or use that as a variable also
local lcKey
lcKey = '10045223'
Select Memo From expertcorr_memoinv ;
     WHERE Keymemo=m.lcKey ;
     into array laMemo

* Update with that value
Update expertcorr_memoinv ;
    Set Memo = laMemo[1] ;
    WHERE Keydoc Like "UBOA"
```

This is only for divide & conquer strategy that one may find easier to follow. Other than that writing it with a single SQL is just fine.

PS: In VFP you don't use backticks at all.
Single quotes, double quotes and opening closing square brackets are not used as identifiers but all those three are used for string literals.

```
'This is a string literal'
"This is a string literal"
[This is a string literal] 

"My name is John O'hara"
'We need 3.5" disk'
[Put 3.5" disk into John's computer]
```

There are subtle differences between them, which I think is an advanced topic and that you may never need to know.

Also [] is used for array indexer.
Any one of them could also be used for things like table name, alias name, file name ... (name expression) - still they are string literals, parentheses make it a name expression. ie:

```
select * from ('MyTable') ...

copy to ("c:\my folder\my file.txt") type delimited
```